# How to delete files/folder from ubuntu one cloud

Tags: ubuntu-one, files

I cannot delete files from my cloud account.

Please tell me how to delete files/folder from my Ubuntu One cloud account.

Answer (score -1):

In U1 you can only stop syncronize folders, not files. So, in Nautilus, for the folder you want to delete from U1, you can press right-click and then in Ubuntu One select stop syncronising this folder.